# How to create android app running on top of another app

Tags: android-widget, android-service, android

I want to develop a program like button savior (which runs on top of a another app and we can press menu, back buttons on top of a running app). So user do not need to press hardware buttons to access menu, back functionalities.

I want to do the same but to do it I have to run a app on top of another app.

How can I do this?

-Lasith.

Comment: i did not quite get your question? can you explaine yourself better

Comment: Ok, in my android tab external hardware buttons like menu, back, search and browse are not working (which is a fault of tab hardware and not the android). So I want to add the behavior of those buttons in to the touch display itself. Button savior is a nice tool which is doing the same for android.

Comment: E.g. Assume you are reading a book with adobe reader. Then with my custom button application should be a transparent application and I should eb able to give adobe reader's menu with my menu button in  the transparent UI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Robotium: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/

It seems to be doing what you want to do. You can take a look at the code and figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think that what you are looking for is creating something like Input Method (IME), there is a good tutorial to start with on [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html), another thing you can do is to create an activity which contains your virtual controller, distribute that as a lib and then if someone need it they can downloads and register your component into their project, something like what [AdMobs](http://www.admob.com/) does.